# Docker run java app

Tags: docker

I have a simple hello world java app and I want to build Docker image which runs it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ADD dist/JavaApplication1.jar /JavaApplication1.jar
RUN chmod +x /JavaApplication1.jar
CMD ["/usr/bin/java -jar /JavaApplication1.jar"] # or CMD ["java -jar /JavaApplication1.jar"]
```

I build it by:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

And run it by:

```
docker run -tdi myapp
```

but it throws:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 105f043e565e465639e15d78e92dc74e64562faa510fae5d6ff48da3a58c0125: [8] System error: exec: "java -jar /JavaApplication1.jar": stat java -jar /JavaApplication1.jar: no such file or directory
```

When run it by:

```
docker run -ti myapp bash
```

and do ls, the file is there and when I run "/usr/bin/java -jar /JavaApplication1.jar" then everything is ok. Where is problem?

My docker version: 1.9.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On docker 1.9.1 either of your approaches works for me:

```
exec: "/usr/bin/java -jar /JavaApplication1.jar": stat /usr/bin/java -jar /JavaApplication1.jar: no such file or directory
```

And that is consistent with [documentation for CMD](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#cmd)

Basically you can use:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
CMD ["param1","param2"]
CMD command param1 param2
```

That would suggest first arg is a binary not a whole cmd, and that's the reason of your error. If you split up cmd as on example above that it will work just fine.

```
FROM java:8
ADD dist/JavaApplication1.jar /JavaApplication1.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/JavaApplication1.jar"]
```

Bonus: `chmod +x` is not needed

Comment: Oh, I thought that it will be some "stupid" thing.  Thanks.